# Initializing pointer to NULL in C

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, cygwin

*(I'm sorry for the vague title, I really didn't know what to put.)*

I wrote [this C program](http://ideone.com/xHQ49C) for homework. I've spent the past four hours attempting to debug it, but I am BRAND new to C. **I'm not asking for the program to be debugged/fixed, please read on.**

**My code**

```
struct olnode {
    int eventnr;
    int eventfq;
    struct olnode *next;
};
typedef struct olnode olnode;

void srchfreq(olnode *list, int xfrequency, olnode **new)
{
    olnode **previous;
    **previous = NULL;

}
```

> **Error**: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'olnode' from type 'void *'
>    **previous = NULL;

The gist of the program is that it should take a random number `eventnr`, determine if it's already in the ordered list `*list` (which has nodes of type `olnode`), then either a) add it to the end of the list if it's not there, or b) update the frequency `eventfq` if it is there. (The list needs to be self-adjusting and keep the list ordered by most frequent to least frequent. Specific order if multiple numbers have the same frequency does not matter.)

My problem was that every time `srchfreq()` would run, `srchevent()` would result in an infinite loop the next time it ran. I inserted some code from a friend in as my `srchfreq()` function (the code in the above link), yet on my computer and on Ideone it won't compile because I'm initializing `**previous = NULL;` on line 149. My friend, using the exact same version of gcc, does not get that error. Our `srchfreq()` functions are identical, and we're both using Cygwin on Windows 7.

So, my two questions:

- Primarily, why does `**previous = NULL;` cause an error whereas it works perfectly on my friend's machine?
- Secondarily, if willing to look, do any glaring issues stand out that could cause the problem of `srchfreq()` breaking the next iteration of `srchevent()`? I used gdb for hours and could not figure out where the problem was.

*Again, the primary issue is with the compilation error, and I'll mark the question as answered if that question is answered. The secondary question is just additional in case anyone happens to notice any issues, I'm NOT asking for the entire code to be debugged.*

Comment: Please don't link to external sites to show your code. Ask a small, concise, complete example and include the smallest example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Okay, my apologies. I'll try to grab a snippet of code and update my question.

Answer (score 1):

`typeof(**previous)` is `olnode` and you cannot assign `NULL` to it.

You perhaps wanted:

```
previous = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a variable named `previous`, which is a pointer to a pointer to an `olnode`.

```
olnode **previous;
```

`**previous` is of type `olnode`. Your next line of code attempts to dereference `previous` twice, and then store `NULL` in whatever location it got. That won’t work, because `previous` was never initialized. Also, the compiler may not know how to cast a `NULL` to type `olnode`, which explains the error message you got.

```
**previous = NULL; // won't work
```

You should initialize `previous` this way instead:

```
olnode **previous;
previous = NULL;
```

Or this:

```
olnode **previous = NULL;
```

About your second question: in `srchfreq`, you never set `previous` to anything. Then you try to dereference `previous` in two places, with `*previous`. That is going to cause a segmentation fault, but I haven’t looked at your code enough to know how you should change it.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the other answers, your code is incorrectly trying to set the contents of the pointer-to-pointer to NULL, rather than the pointer-to-pointer itself. I'll explain why it may work on some compilers.

The definition of the NULL macro can be literally anything in C, as long as it "expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant" (C11 7.19).

In practice, NULL is almost certainly defined either as

```
#define NULL 0
```

or

```
#define NULL (void*)0
```

Depending on which form is used by your compiler, and depending on how picky your compiler is, logically incorrect expressions like `int x = NULL;` may or may not compile. Because `int x = 0;` is obviously perfectly valid C, but `int x = (void*)0;` is a type conflict.